# mysqli_real_connect(): (HY000/2002): No such file or directory after moving mysql to different partition

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, centos7

My phpMyAdmin is running on Centos 7. phpMyAdmin was working fine before I migrate mysql from /var/lib/mysql to /db partition. I have edited /etc/my.cnf according. After the migration I'm able to connect to mysql in command line. But the mention error is returning when I try to connect from phpMyAdmin. What could be the reason for this?

Comment: Have you shutdown the old mysql server? also check in  /etc/phpMyAdmin/config.inc.php if there is the  correct server and port . If there is al right login with mysql and check if the tables are all there or if something went wrong with your migration.

Comment: Unless you over-ride the socket in config.inc.php, it just uses what's set in the PHP configuration. I suggest looking in the PHP configuration file for the socket to fix this for your entire system, rather than editing the phpMyAdmin configuration which would only change that one application.